# How can I set niceness and process affinity at the same time?

Tags: linux, bash, process, linux-kernel, cpu-usage

Is there a way to set the nice value of process and its affinity at the same time? For example:

```
 taskset -c 0,1 nice -20 proc
```

Update: It works like this. I thought it must me something more complex.

Comment: are you sure it works like that : o ? Another way would be to download schedtool and do `schedtool -a 0,1 -n 20 sleep 30`

Comment: I've just used that command -- works.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using PID-Based Scheduling Tools

Many CPU scheduling tools want a PID rather than a command. The following *seems* to work on my system:

```
# Using shell expansion to reliably use correct PID.
sudo nice -n18 schedtool -a 0,1 $(sleep 30 & echo $!) &
```

by using a shell expansion to get the PID of the last backgrounded process, but it seems hackish. The following seems cleaner, IMHO, but your mileage (and obviously the specifics of the scheduling tool you're using) may vary.

```
# Cleaner example with less hacking around.
nice -n18 sleep 30 &
sudo schedtool -a 0,1 $!
```

#### Flags That Take Commands

If supported, the -e flag seems to do what's needed by allowing a command instead of a PID. For example:

```
sudo schedtool -a 0,1 -e nice -n18 sleep 30 &
```

Comment: You can set the nice priority in schedtool as well with the `-n` option

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `taskset -c 0,1 && nice -20 proc`? If taskset succeeds, then nice will be called.

Comment: `taskset` requires a `-p pid` or a command as it's final argument.